# Changing database type at runtime using EntityFramework

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

Is it possible to change database type at runtime? If yes, how it can be done? I am using EntityFramework 6.

Background about the question:
*I have an application that initially does not have database access. A user first has to go through "installation" process and provide information about the database(including database type eg. MySql or MsSql).*

I would like to avoid having 2 contexts if possible. If necessary I can provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the connection string at runtime using the following...

`DbContext` has a constructor that can be overloaded with the name of the connection string, or the connection string itself.

```
public partial class EntityName: DbContext {
    public EntityName(): base("name=EntityName") {}
    public EntityName(string connectionString): base(connectionString) {}
}

var connString = "PopulateConnString";
Using (var ctx = new EntityName(EntityConnectionStringBuilder)
{
   // Do stuff
}
```